# Entity Framework 6 Handle Transaction At Database Level

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure that uses transactions at a database level (the transactions are handled within the stored procedure itself). This means I need to tell Entity Framework not to handle transactions.

Now using database first model I can import the stored procedure and have an auto generated context class that looks like the following:

```
 public virtual int MyStoredProcedure()
 {         
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("MyStoreProcedure");
 }
```

I can add my own method to the `DbContext` class that looks like the following:

```
public virtual int MyStoredProcedureWithoutTransaction()
{
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "MyStoredProcedure")
}
```

My question is does the following code also behave the same as the `MyStoredProcedureWithoutTransaction()` in terms of transaction management:

```
MyContext context = new MyContext();
context.Database.UseTransaction(null);
context.MyStoredProcedure();
```

If it does I would prefer to use the second version as it will have the advantage of using the auto generated code from Entity Framework.

Comment: You could probably run a Sql Server Profiler to confirm that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone comes across this post and is wondering the answer is No!

```
context.Database.UseTransaction(null);
```

Is not the same as using `TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction` on the `ExecuteSqlCommand` overloaded method.

However the following does work and can be used how I originally wanted:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
```

In the application I simply created a base repository class as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityFrameworkNonTransactionRepository<T> where T : DbContext, new()
{
    protected T _context;

    protected BaseEntityFrameworkNonTransactionRepository()
    {
        _context = new T();
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved  my solution :) Cool ! Thank you!    Updated  EF version  from 6.0.0.0 to 6.4.4 this version contants  EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands  method.  I